# combinatorical\probabalistic interpretation of $(x^n)/n!$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, exponential-function

The expression $x^n / n!$ appears in a the infinite sum definig $e^x$ and similar terms in the sums defining $\cos(x)$, $\sin(x)$, etc.
I would like to know if there is some combinatorial/probabilistic meaning or analogy to the term $x^n / n!$ and appropriately an example of a scenario of selection or decision making that could be represented by a consequtive sum of these terms similar to the infinite sums defining $e^x$ or $\cos(x)/\sin(x)$.

In other words: some probabalistic/Combinatorical scenario whose calculation would converge to one of these functions ($e^x/\cos(x)/\sin(x)$).
Thanks alot

Comment: I am not qualified to really talk about this, but this might be of interest. There is a category theoretic/algebraic idea called groupoid cardinality. Taken from [Qiaochu Yuan's blog](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/groupoid-cardinality/),  "Let $s$ be a finite set and consider the groupoid of $s$-colored finite sets ... the groupoid cardinality is $\sum_{n\ge0 }\frac{|s|^n}{n!}$."

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/620593/119261.